# Centerpoint of the visible GeoJSON path with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I am working on a project that is displaying a map centered on a selected country and the neighboring countries, all with GeoJSON. I'm wondering if there is a way to get the centerpoint of the visible portions of a country?

Part of the project involves adding country labels as markers. So far, I can add the markers on:

1. The country centerpoint
2. The centerpoint of the visible bounding box

The first method more than likely places the label outside of view (or partially in view) and the second improves upon this but can put the labels in areas outside of a country because the bounding box is an overly simplified area for a country. Ideally I would be able to get the clipped area of a shape so that I can figure out the centerpoint of that to see if label placement for this will be improved, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can do spatial transformations like this with leaflet.js on it's own, but sounds like [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/) could have the necessary functions.  Assuming you have your country geojson and your viewport bbox, something like this might work:

```
turf.pointOnSurface(turf.intersect(countryPoly, viewportBbox));
```

turf is supposed to play well with leaflet.  (haven't tried it myself yet, though).

Comment: I had been looking for something like turf.js but hadn't come across that... so thank you! I've made some progress so this is in the running for "correct answer" :)

Comment: Added this as accepted. Turf can get you some pretty good results and has lots of useful functionality. Using with GeoJSON/Leaflet is really simple.